# Delete element in JSONPath Java

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I have a `JSON` file like this:

```
{
    "objects": [{
            "type": "FirstType",
            (...)
            "details": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "FirstElementOfTheFirstType",
                "font": "18px arial"
            },
            "id": "18e"
        },
        (...)
        {
            "type": "SecondType",
            (...)
            "details": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "FirstElementOfTheSecondType",
                "font": "18px arial"
            },
            "id": "18f"
        }
    ],
    "background": "#ffffff"
}
```

My goal is to delete nodes of a certain `type` and `id` in `details` F.e. if I would like to delete elements of `type` named `FirstType` and `id` of `1`.I would get:

```
{
    "objects": [
        (...)
        {
            "type": "SecondType",
            (...)
            "details": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "FirstElementOfTheSecondType",
                "font": "18px arial"
            },
            "id": "18f"
        }
    ],
    "background": "#ffffff"
}
```

I think I partialy achieved this:

```
final DocumentContext jsonContext = JsonPath.parse(element.getJsonContent());
jsonContext.delete("$['objects'][?(@.type == 'FirstType')][?(@.details.id == '1')]");
```

But I would like to consider `type` and `id` in `details` as well, but I am not sure if two filter expressions are written correctly. I feel like I stuck here

**EDITED: Solved**

Ok. For future references, correct form goes like this:

```
DocumentContext jsonContext = JsonPath.parse(element.getJsonContent());
                jsonContext.delete("$['objects'][?(@.type == 'FirstType' && @.details.id == 1)]");
                element.setJsonContent(jsonContext.jsonString());
```

Comment: You can use `&&` in JsonPath: `"$['objects'][?(@.type == 'FirstType' && @details.id == '1')]"`